# SQL Server Aggregates giving unusual values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have these two queries to test my output

```
SELECT DISTINCT( providerId ), 
               SUM(( claimCount )), 
               SUM(paidAmount), 
               SUM(provallowed), 
               SUM(patresp), 
               provId, 
               cliCode, 
               asctype, 
               payerid, 
               procCode 
FROM   TempCounts tt, 
       TempClient tct 
WHERE  ( tct.npi = tt.provid 
          OR tct.txcode = tt.provid ) 
       AND CLICODE = 'XXX' 
GROUP  BY tt.provid, 
          providerId, 
          cliCode, 
          asctype, 
          payerid, 
          procCode
```

--

```
SELECT DISTINCT( providerid ), 
               claimCount, 
               paidamount, 
               provallowed, 
               patresp, 
               provid, 
               CLICODE, 
               asctype, 
               payerid, 
               proccode 
FROM   TempCounts tt, 
       TempClient tct 
WHERE  ( tct.npi = tt.provid 
          OR tct.txcode = tt.provid ) 
       AND CLICODE = 'XXX'
```

summing the unaggregated results from the second query should give the aggregated values in the first query, but my data sets end up like 
first data set

```
15086   7   216.16  0.00    35.00   1609950203  XXX     216     72040
15086   7   227.36  0.00    21.00   1609950203  XXX     216     72070
```

second data set

```
15086   1   30.88   0.00    5.00    1609950203  XXX     216     72040
15086   1   32.48   0.00    3.00    1609950203  XXX     216     72070
```

Can't for the life of me see what I'm missing and stared at it so long I'm code blind.  Any suggestions?

Comment: what are you expecting the results to be?

Comment: Can you add the table prefix to the columns, so we know which columns go with which tables?

Comment: basically in this case since there is one record per proccode, the sum should be the same as the unsummed value.

Comment: Why is `providerid` in brackets? `DISTINCT` applies to the whole column list not just that column. If you remove the `DISTINCT` in the second query I assume that the result is 7 identical rows for each group?

Comment: @MartinSmith - yes.  I knew that was the case but was struggling to get around it.   finally hit on the solution (always seems to happen after I post the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finally. because the tempClient table has multiple records based on the npi and txcode field (i.e. a record can have multiple instances of txcode for each npi. I thought I was filtering for that as the same query against mysql gave correct results. The solution was adding tt.npi and tt.txcode to the groupby statement.

Answer (score 3):

The two data sets can be different because of the DISTINCT option.

Therefore, the unaggregated query returns only a limited number of lines, those which are different from each other.

On the first query, the DISTINCT option is useless since you have all grouping columns in the result.

Comment: Yep. If there are 7 duplicate rows that would explain it. Multiplying all the aggregates in the 2nd result by 7 gives the first result. Maybe these are being duplicated by the odd join condition.

Comment: yes.  I figured it out finally.  because the tempClient table has multiple records based on the npi and txcode field (i.e. a record can have multiple instances of txcode for each npi.  I thought I was filtering for that as the same query against mysql gave correct results.   The solution was adding tt.npi and tt.txcode to the groupby statement.